# Collection SwipeView Xamarin Form not passing args

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, uicollectionview, command

For a strange reason, I can't find a way to fire the parameters. I have tried almost everything I know. if I do it without the parameters the function gets fired. but I need the args from the collection view. At this point, I just want to use it from behind the page. can someone share an example of how to fire this from the back page C# using the information from the collection view x:name: NotificationList
I'm using normal things like

```
INotifyPropertyChanged and 
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

xaml

```
<CollectionView x:Name="NotificationList"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListData}"  SelectionMode="None">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <SwipeView>
                            <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                <SwipeItems>
                                    <SwipeItemView>
                                       <StackLayout Padding="15" Spacing="10" BackgroundColor="Red" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <Label Text="Delete" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                                                 <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                 <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference NotificationList}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}"/>
                                                 </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </SwipeItemView>
                                </SwipeItems>
                            </SwipeView.RightItems>
                            
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">
                                <Label Text="{Binding subject}" FontAttributes="Bold"   />
                                <Label Text="{Binding body}"    />
                             
                                
                            </StackLayout>
                        </SwipeView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

ViewModel

```
public ICommand DeleteCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command<NitificationModel>((arg) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (arg != null)
                        {

                            
                             ex.DeleteNotification(arg);
                            
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.Write(ex);
                    }

                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: I feel that your problem could related with the datatype of your binding `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"` change this and instead use any property of the `ListData` collection object. Update your Command<Type> accordingly. Do this to get an idea.

Comment: Also you might want to change the Command a little bit too. The way you have it, it will be creating and returning a new instance every time this is bound. I guess that's not what you want. Instead have the regular getter property and then do the initialization and assignment of the Command in the Constructor

`public ICommand DeleteCommand {get; }`

//ctor

`DeleteCommand = new Command<Type>(arg => {});`